# how to create factory pattern in c# without modifying scaffolding (the creators)

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, .net-4.5, factory-pattern

Today i had an interview and i was asked to create a factory pattern in c# in such a way that I could just add Concrete classes and not have to modify the scaffolding (the creators).

Could anyone please solve this with example.

thanks,

Comment: Huh? I think that's a poorly phrased question. I'm not sure how the terms "scaffolding" nor "creators" apply here. That's certainly not standard terminology when talking about factories. Are you looking for the abstract factory pattern? An Inversion of Control container? `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`?

Comment: factory pattern only..

Comment: Then I don't know what you're asking. The factory pattern is basically a method that you use to create a complex object. That's it. It's one of the simplest design patterns, there are no tricks. It's just a method. Saying you don't want to modify the scaffolding makes as much sense as saying you don't want to modify the elephants.

Comment: My best guess is that they were looking for an answer either about IoC or [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but are really bad at asking questions and don't fully understand what the factory pattern is themselves.

Comment: If this is really how the question was posed in the interview, then most likely the interviewer was wanting to provoke clarifying questions.  The kinds of questions you ask in response to an under-constrained problem are often more informative (in an interviewing context) than whatever solution to some particular variant of the requirements you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

The `Abstract Factory` design pattern abstracts the process of creating (a family of) objects.

Clients (the creators) refer to that abstraction (`AbstractFactory` interface) and are independent of an 
implementation (i.e., how the objects are created,  which classes are instantiated).
You can add concrete classes (`Factory1`, `Factory2`, ...) without having to modify the clients
(creators).

See the following UML diagrams (if you aren't sure how to implement, please let me know).

[image: UML Diagram not found, please let me know]

For further discussion see the GoF Design Patterns Memory for learning
object-oriented design & programming / Abstract Factory (Solution and Code Samples)
at http://w3sdesign.com.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to have the factory return an interface which all of the concrete classes would implement. The factory would then use dependency injection to have a specific concrete class injected and would be controlled when registering the class with the IoC container for that interface. The factory would only use interface methods to build up that object though. Hope that makes sense and matches what you are asking. By scaffolding I am assuming you are meaning the actual factory logic.